# ¿Cómo agregar varias llaves foráneas dentro de una sentencia CREATE TABLE en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo agregar 3 llaves foráneas dentro de una sentencia `CREATE TABLE` en MySQL?

Mis 3 tablas son las siguientes:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    id_cliente integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- PK
    nombre varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    apellidos varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    sexo varchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK (sexo="Masculino" OR sexo="Femenino"),
    telefono varchar(15)NOT NULL,
    direccion varchar(100)NOT NULL,
    email varchar(30)NOT NULL  
);

CREATE TABLE empleados (
    id_empleado integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- PK
    nombre varchar(15),
    apellidos varchar(30),
    sexo varchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK (sexo="Masculino" OR sexo="Femenino"),
    telefono varchar(15),
    direccion varchar(100),
    email varchar(30),    
    salario decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE motocicleta (
    id_motocicleta integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- PK
    tipo_moto varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    marca varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    modelo varchar(18) NOT NULL,
    color varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    stock integer NOT NULL,
    precio_venta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    fecha_registro datetime NOT NULL      
);
```

Aquí es donde tengo dudas de cómo agregar las 3 llaves foráneas de mis tablas principales.

```
CREATE TABLE venta_motocicletas (
    id_venta integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,    
    id_empleado integer NOT NULL, -- FK
    id_cliente integer NOT NULL, -- FK
    id_motocicleta integer NOT NULL, -- FK
    cantidad_motos integer NOT NULL,
    precio_venta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    total_venta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    fecha_venta date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_idempleado FOREIGN KEY (id_empleado) REFERENCES empleados(id_empleado)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE -- solo esto logré hacerlo
);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo intentaste agregar las demás claves foráneas? ¿Querés evitar los `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: ¿Es [este](/q/553437) tu caso?

Answer (score 2):

Tengo entendido que si quieres agregar llaves foraneas o la relacion en tu tabla venta de las otras tablas, es de esta forma

```
    CREATE TABLE venta_motocicletas (
    id_venta integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    id_empleado integer NOT NULL, -- FK
    id_cliente integer NOT NULL, -- FK
    id_motocicleta integer NOT NULL, -- FK
    cantidad_motos integer NOT NULL,
    precio_venta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    total_venta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    fecha_venta date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_idempleado FOREIGN KEY (id_empleado) REFERENCES empleados(id_empleado),
    CONSTRAINT fk_idcliente FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente),
    CONSTRAINT fk_idmotocicleta FOREIGN KEY (id_motocicleta) REFERENCES motocicleta(id_motocicleta)
    
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Yo suponía que en cada CONSTRAINT debía escribir un ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE en cada CONSTRAINT

Comment: Varia según  tus requisito y/o aplicación, hay casos en los que si es necesario por cada llave foránea. Pero como te digo depende de que es lo que busques